# Debugging Swift 3 on OSX 10.10

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3

To keep up to date with the recent Swift changes, our team plans to migrate our code to Swift 3. Once this happens we can no longer use Xcode 7.x.  However as Xcode 8 does not run on 10.10, how do we debug 10.10 only issues?

Remote debugging does not seem possible.